# Restructure each row of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

(Please don't mind the title, i didn't know exactly how to correctly name it)I currently have a multi dimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [French Navy] => Array
            (
                [84] => 2XL   
                [quantity] => 999
                [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36786
                [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 182
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
                [83] => XL    
                [82] => L     
                [81] => M     
                [80] => S     
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Classic Red] => Array
            (
                [84] => 2XL   
                [quantity] => 999
                [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36780
                [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 178
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
                [83] => XL    
                [82] => L     
                [81] => M     
                [80] => S     
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Burgundy] => Array
            (
                [84] => 2XL   
                [quantity] => 999
                [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36774
                [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 106
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
                [83] => XL    
                [82] => L     
                [81] => M     
                [80] => S     
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Bright Royal] => Array
            (
                [84] => 2XL   
                [quantity] => 999
                [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36768
                [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 176
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
                [83] => XL    
                [82] => L     
                [81] => M     
                [80] => S     
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Bottle Green] => Array
            (
                [84] => 2XL   
                [quantity] => 999
                [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36762
                [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 86
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
                [83] => XL    
                [82] => L     
                [81] => M     
                [80] => S     
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Black] => Array
            (
                [84] => 2XL   
                [quantity] => 999
                [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36756
                [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 75
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
                [83] => XL    
                [82] => L     
                [81] => M     
                [80] => S     
            )

    )

)
```

What i want to do, is reduce each iteration down to it's own array, so i can access the key values as names (if that makes sense). Something like this:

```
Array
(
  [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36790
  [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
  [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 182
  [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 84
  [quantity] => 999
  [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes1] => 2XL => [id1] => 83
  [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes2] => L   => [id2] => 84
  [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes3] => S   => [id3] => 85
  [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes4] => M   => [id4] => 86   
  [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => French Navy
)
```

The current php code I'm using to produce the first array is this:

```
$colours = array();
                        $sizes = array();
                        $color = "";
                        $id = "";
                        $quantity = "";
                        //$count = count($colours);

                        foreach($product_combinations as $key => $product_combination){
                            if($key > -1){
                                if(
                                    $product_combinations[$key+1]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours']
                                    == $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours']
                                  ){

                                    $color  = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours'];
                                    $id = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];
                                    $sizes[$id] = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_sizes'];
                                    $quantity = $product_combinations[$key]['quantity'];
                                    $sizes['quantity'] = $quantity;

                                    /* Dont forget theses*/
                                    $sizes['product_colour_sizes_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_id'];
                                    $sizes['product_colour_sizes_product_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_product_id'];
                                    $sizes['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'];
                                    $sizes['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'] =$product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];

                                } else {
                                    array_push($colours, 
                                    array(
                                        $color => $sizes

                                    ));

                                    unset($sizes);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

How can i go about doing this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Merge all these arrays into one? If so, under what condition?

Comment: The term for converting a multi-dimensional array to a 1D array is "flatten", i.e. flatten the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: your desired structure doesn't make sense, `product_colour_sizes_name_sizes1` and other similar would still need to yield another array inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to make your input array to single dimensional array:

```
echo '<pre>';

$new_product_combinations = array();

foreach ($product_combinations as $k => $v) {
    $array = array();
    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
            if (is_int($k2)) {
                $j = $i++;
                $array['product_colour_sizes_name_sizes' . $j] = $v2;
                $array['id' . $j] = $k2;
            } else {
                $array[$k2] = $v2;
            }
        }
        $array['product_colour_sizes_name_colours'] = $k1;
    }
    print_r($array); // output single combination
    $new_product_combinations[] = $array;
}

print_r($new_product_combinations);
```

Above code will output as:

```
Array
(
    [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes1] => 2XL
    [id1] => 84
    [quantity] => 999
    [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36786
    [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
    [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 182
    [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
    [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes2] => XL
    [id2] => 83
    [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes3] => L
    [id3] => 82
    [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes4] => M
    [id4] => 81
    [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes5] => S
    [id5] => 80
    [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => French Navy
) 
:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes1] => 2XL
            [id1] => 84
            [quantity] => 999
            [product_colour_sizes_id] => 36786
            [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1276
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 182
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 80
            [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes2] => XL
            [id2] => 83
            [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes3] => L
            [id3] => 82
            [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes4] => M
            [id4] => 81
            [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes5] => S
            [id5] => 80
            [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => French Navy
        ) 
        :
)
```

Hope this will help you.